# What's meant by the "this" context?

Tags: java, android

I have looked at a lot of android tutorials over the internet. In these tutorials they use the `this` context for the context everywhere. I know what `this` keyword means in Java, but I can't make equal this, with the `this` keyword in Android programming. For example, at `AlertDialog.Builder`, on the developer.android.com site, there is only one reference at the parameters to the Context, but I can't learn what this `this` means here.

Comment: take a look a this post, it could help you to understand. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3572463/what-is-context-in-android

Comment: The only thing that came to mind when I saw this question was "What is the meaning of this!"

Answer (score 12, accepted):

if you have an Activity you can use `this` because:

- `this` is the current instance of a class
- an Activity is inherits from the class "Context"

so you can use your current Activity as a Context.

Look [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) for the Acitivty doc

and [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/thiskey.html) for an explanation of `this`

Comment: . `this` is the current instance of the classe , , it's an instance :)

Answer (score 0):

If you know `"this"` variable.. then u may also know that it holds reference for the current object.. so if some method asks for a Context object you can pass `this` variable only when it extends classes like Context or Activity.. Because Activity implements context so obeviously its a Context

Answer (score 0):

Context of current class is called This in Android.

Answer (score 0):

[Here is another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3572463/what-is-context-in-android) where they explain `Context`. As activities and services extend  `Context`, the *this context* is a reference to *this activity or service*.

Answer (score 0):

The keyword `this` is simply a reference -- within an instance of a class -- to itself.

There are two common uses of "this" in Android.  These aren't particular to Android, but are valid in Java in general.

1. `this.getResources()` says to call the `getResources()` method on `this` instance.  The `this` portion of it is usually unnecessary and used implicitly.
2. `Foo.this.getResources()` could be called from an inner class.  This could be handy if the inner class defines `getResources()` also, but you want the version defined in the other class.

Answer (score 0):

**`this` is a reference to the current object**

You can use `this` to refer to any current instance and any instance of its super class.

**If your class extends Activity**. It is a case of inheritance. your class is subclass and Activity class is parent class. then you can use this keyword to get instance of Activity
 beacause Activity class is super class of your class. This is ***implicit casting***

also Activity class `Context` as superclass. so you can refer the instance of that class using this keyword.

Thanks